# Parallel processing in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am trying to run a for loop in parallel which includes trying a eras model in parallel. Following is the code:

```
function init_population(pop :: _population)
        addprocs(16)

    @sync @parallel for i in 1:pop.size
    @everywhere ran=sample(1:202,10,replace=false)
    @everywhere w=get_weights(ran)  ####keras model
    @everywhere gg=_genotype(ran,w)   ### composite type
    @everywhere m,v=get_mean_variance(gg)  ####func doing calculation
    @everywhere pp=_phenotype(m,v)    ### composite type
    @everywhere fitn=get_fitness(pp)   ####func doing calculation
    @everywhere new_guy = _individual(gg,pp,fitn)     ### composite type
    @everywhere push!(pop.individuals, new_guy)
end
return pop
end
```

The error I am getting ::

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: sample not defined
eval at ./boot.jl:235
eval_ew_expr at ./distributed/macros.jl:116 [inlined]
#135 at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:319
run_work_thunk at ./distributed/process_messages.jl:56
#remotecall_fetch#140 at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:344
remotecall_fetch at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:344
#remotecall_fetch#144 at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:372
remotecall_fetch at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:372
#33 at ./distributed/macros.jl:102
#remotecall_fetch#140(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:345
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Base.Distributed.LocalProcess, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:344
#remotecall_fetch#144(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:372
remotecall_fetch(::Function, ::Int64, ::Expr, ::Vararg{Expr,N} where N) at ./distributed/remotecall.jl:372
(::##73#75)() at ./distributed/macros.jl:102
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end() at ./task.jl:287
 [2] macro expansion at ./distributed/macros.jl:112 [inlined]
 [3] evolutionary_loop(::_population) at ./untitled-75c3e04a7f530386f03caa1b6d061e62:372
 [4] include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:522
 [5] include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at /Users/yash/.julia/v0.6/Compat/src/Compat.jl:88
 [6] (::Atom.##112#116{String,String})() at /Users/yash/.julia/v0.6/Atom/src/eval.jl:109
 [7] withpath(::Atom.##112#116{String,String}, ::Void) at /Users/yash/.julia/v0.6/CodeTools/src/utils.jl:30
 [8] withpath(::Function, ::String) at /Users/yash/.julia/v0.6/Atom/src/eval.jl:38
 [9] hideprompt(::Atom.##111#115{String,String}) at /Users/yash/.julia/v0.6/Atom/src/repl.jl:67
 [10] macro expansion at /Users/yash/.julia/v0.6/Atom/src/eval.jl:106 [inlined]
 [11] (::Atom.##110#114{Dict{String,Any}})() at ./task.jl:80
while loading untitled-75c3e04a7f530386f03caa1b6d061e62, in expression starting on line 395
```

I am not sure how to do remote call and how it works. I basically to run the for loop in 16 processes .pop.size=100...and I need to run them on the same array.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is missing
`@everywhere using StatsBase` 
Since each worker is an additional process the module `StatsBase` should be imported across all workers.

If you use `@parallel` loop you do not need neither `@sync` nor `@everywhere` inside the loop. `@parallel` simply divides the loop across the workers and executes parts on each worker. Depending on what you want to do you are probably missing aggregator function so it usually is:

```
@parallel (my_agg_function) for i in 1:n
   # do something - job will be evenly split across workers
end
```

Please also consider using `pmap` instead of `@parallel`.

`@everywhere` executes the command across all workers. In parallel simulations it is usually used to things such as initializing variables/simulation states or importing libraries. Please note that if you wish to send data across workers you might want to use `ParallelDataTransfer.jl`.

Last but not least `addprocs(16)` inside a function is usually not a good pattern - new 16 `julia` processes will be spawn each time the function is invoked. Use the `-p` command line option instead (e.g. start Julia with `julia -p 16` command).